# Getting a bunch of extra output when decrypting an encrypted file. What could be the problem in my code?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'm new to cryptography and this here is the code that I wrote filling in the skeleton code provided by my assigner(please don't mind the structure). I describe the problem below this code.

```java
public class FileEncryptor {

    private static final String progName = "FileEncryptor";
    private static final int bufSize = 128;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedInputStream in = null;          // A buffered input stream to read from
        BufferedOutputStream out = null;        // And a buffered output stream to write to
        SecretKeyFactory kf = null;             // Something to create a key for us
        KeySpec ks = null;                      // This is how we specify what kind of key we want it to generate
        byte[] salt = new byte[20];             // Some salt for use with PBKDF2, only not very salty
        SecretKey key = null;                   // The key that it generates
        Cipher cipher = null;                   // The cipher that will do the real work
        SecretKeySpec keyspec = null;           // How we pass the key to the Cipher
        int bytesRead = 0;                      // Number of bytes read into the input file buffer

        // First, check the user has provided all the required arguments, and if they haven't, tell them then exit
        if(args.length != 4) {
            printUsageMessage(); System.exit(1);
        }

        // Open the input file
        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(args[1]));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            printErrorMessage("Unable to open input file: " + args[1], null);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // And then the output file
        try {
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(args[2]));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            printErrorMessage("Unable to open output file: " + args[2], e);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Create a PBKDF2 secret key factory
        String algorithm = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256";
        try {
            kf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            printErrorMessage("Specified algorithm could not be found: " + algorithm , e);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Set up a KeySpec for password-based key generation of a 128-bit key
        ks = new PBEKeySpec(args[3].toCharArray(),salt,4096, 128);

        // Now run the passphrase through PBKDF2 to get the key
        try {
            key = kf.generateSecret(ks);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            printErrorMessage("The key spec provided is invalid: " + keyspec, e);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Get the byte encoded key value as a byte array
        byte[] aeskey = key.getEncoded();

        // Now generate a Cipher object for AES encryption in ECBC mode with PKCS #5 padding
        // Use ECB for the first task, then switch to CBC for versions 2 and 3
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            printErrorMessage("No Such Algorithm Exception when creating main cipher", e);
            System.exit(2);
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            printErrorMessage("No Such Padding Exception when creating main cipher",e);
            System.exit(2);
        }

        // Set a variable to indicate whether we're in encrypt or decrypt mode, based upon args[0]
        int cipherMode = -1;
        char mode = Character.toLowerCase(args[0].charAt(0));
        switch (mode) {
            case 'e' : cipherMode = Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE; break;
            case 'd' : cipherMode = Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE; break;
            default: printUsageMessage(); System.exit(1);
        }

        // Set up a secret key specification, based on the 16-byte (128-bit) AES key array previously generated
        keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(aeskey, "AES");

        // Now initialize the cipher in the right mode, with the keyspec and the ivspec
        try {
            cipher.init(cipherMode, keyspec);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            printErrorMessage("Invalid Key Spec",e); System.exit(2);
        }

        // Set up some input and output byte array buffers
        byte[] inputBuffer = new byte[bufSize];
        byte[] outputBuffer = null;

        // "Prime the pump" - we've got to read something before we can encrypt it
        // and not encrypt anything if we read nothing.
        try {
            bytesRead = in.read(inputBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            printErrorMessage("Error reading input file " + args[1],e1); System.exit(1);
        }

        // As long as we've read something, loop around encrypting, writing and reading
        // bytesRead will be zero if nothing was read, or -1 on EOF - treat them both the same
        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            byte[] input = inputBuffer;
            // Now encrypt this block
            outputBuffer = cipher.update(input);

            // Write the generated block to file
            try {
                out.write(outputBuffer);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                printErrorMessage("Error writing to output file " + args[2],e1); System.exit(1);
            }

            // And read in the next block of the file
            try {
                bytesRead = in.read(inputBuffer);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                printErrorMessage("Error reading input file " + args[1],e1); System.exit(1);
            }
        }

        // Now do the final processing
        try {
            outputBuffer = cipher.doFinal(outputBuffer);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e2) {
            printErrorMessage("Illegal block size encountered while doing final processing: " + outputBuffer.length , e2);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (BadPaddingException e2) {
            printErrorMessage("Bad Padding found", e2);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Write the final block of output
        try {
            out.write(outputBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            printErrorMessage("Error on final write to output file " + args[2],e1); System.exit(1);
        }

        // Close the output files
        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            printErrorMessage("Error closing file", e1);
        }
    }   
}
```

*For convenience I omitted the `printErrorMessage()` and `printUsageMessage()` methods.*

This here seems to be the problem; I am getting a **`BadPaddingException`** and though the code catches that exception I do not know how to handle that exception or what to do with it. I tried removing the `System.exit(1)` line from my code in final processing but then the output files comes out twice the size of my encrypted file which is 256 bytes regardless of the size of my input files(having size less than 256 bytes). So, if my input file contains:

```
hello there
```

And I encrypt it using `key` as the passphrase I get my output file containing something like this:

```
9`ÃLå7}
syXÀ¢Èì´^¾Õn¾AXëC~9‹`Èì´^¾Õn¾AXëC~9‹`Èì´^¾Õn¾AXëC~9‹`Èì´^¾Õn¾AXëC~9‹`Èì´^¾Õn¾AXëC~9‹`Èì´^¾Õn¾AXëC~9‹`Èì´^¾Õn¾AXëC~9‹`0‹ó‚±G¸Y·IñåsòQœ ÙÞç„ò;uîðpoîœ ÙÞç„ò;uîðpoîœ ÙÞç„ò;uîðpoîœ ÙÞç„ò;uîðpoîœ ÙÞç„ò;uîðpoîœ ÙÞç„ò;uîðpoîœ ÙÞç„ò;uîðpoî‡¥ÄQé±uTö/Ú˜Í¤
```

And now when I decrypt this file using the same passphrase `key` I get something like this:

```
hello there                                                                                                                     9`Ì巽
syXÀ¢Ȭ´^¾ծ¾AX냾9`Ȭ´^¾ծ¾AX냾9`Ȭ´^¾ծ¾AX냾9`Ȭ´^¾ծ¾AX냾9`Ȭ´^¾ծ¾AX냾9`Ȭ´^¾ծ¾AX냾9`Ȭ´^¾ծ¾AX냾9`Ȭ´^¾ծ¾AX냾9`Ȭ´^¾ծ¾AX냾9`Ȭ´^¾ծ¾AX냾9`Ȭ´^¾ծ¾AX냾9`Ȭ´^¾ծ¾AX냾9`Ȭ´^¾ծ¾AX냾9`Ȭ´^¾ծ¾AX냾9`Ȭ´^¾ծ¾AX냾9`Ȭ´^¾ծ¾AX냾9`Ȭ´^¾ծ¾AX냾9`Ȭ´^¾ծ¾AX냾9`Ȭ´^¾ծ¾AX냾9`Ȭ´^¾ծ¾AX냾9`
```

How can I get rid of this shit-storm that's trailing my decrypted text?
All helps and suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're ignoring `bytesRead` when passing the `byte[]` to `update()`, even if the buffer isn't full. I'd also suggest using a *single* buffer variable, instead of fiddling with `input` and `inputBuffer`. Finally, your "prime the pump" is bad design, just change your loop to a standard read-process-write, instead of read -> process-write-read.

Comment: @Kayaman I'll remove the extra `byte[]` for input. I am not using `bytesRead` in update because it is an interger variable that contains only the number of bytes read and not the contains. Can I use that information though? How can I do so? And for the loop, that was present in the skeleton code so I can't really do anything much about it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: If you pass a `byte[64]` to `update()`, but there's only 32 bytes read, the method does not know that there are 32 bytes garbage. That's why you're getting garbage.

Comment: @Kayaman How can I solve this issue? Help me.

Comment: Help yourself: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html

Comment: @Kayaman The hard way. "I like it rough, I like it hard.", she said. xD. Okay, I will look into it. Thanks. If you have quick tips then by all means, please share. Have a great day! :)